# How can I show fewer than n columns in a grid view where it has n columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP Grid View; its Datasource is a list of entities. The entity has 11 properties, but I want to show only some of the columns in the grid view.
My Grid View is

```html
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridForResult"
              Caption="Update The Result for the Folloing Students"
              Visible="true" ShowHeader="false">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("TestRoll")%>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="120px">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("Name")%>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="80px">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("Program")%>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In my code behind page, I have bound the grid like this:

```
List<FormGridEntity> gridEntities = new List<FormGridEntity>();
gridEntities = AdmissionResult_BAO.GetAllCandidateAdmissionInfo();
GridForResult.DataSource = gridEntities;
GridForResult.DataBind();
//What Will I need to do here or somewhere else
```

What should I do now?

Comment: @Geoff Appleford: THnx a lot dude!

Comment: @Pankouri - no problem. If you don't know, you can use the `{}` button to format code blocks (or indent everything 4 spaces). For inline code segments, surround your code with backticks - eg a `

Comment: @Geoff Appleford: I Always use {} but since my problem was nor related to indenting so i only put the related code, I never did coding without indenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@V4Vendetta has it right - in your GridView markup, set AutoGenerateColumns="false":

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridForResult" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Caption="Update The Result for the Folloing Students" Visible="true" ShowHeader="false">
```

Alternatively, if you want to define columns in the markup and turn them off individually, you can set the Visible="false" property:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" Visible="false">
```

You don't have to do anything in your code-behind, unless you want to turn columns on/off programatically:

```
GridForResult.Columns[0].Visible = false; // Turns off the first column
```